# Azure Web App connecting to SQL FO Group over Private Link

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database, azure-virtual-network

I would like to know few things about my web apps hosted in Central US connecting to Azure SQL FO group connection string. The Primary SQL is hosted in the same region which is Central US and the Secondary Replica is hosted in East US 2.
I am considering using Private Link for Azure SQL.So  in order for my web app to talk to the Azure SQL over the private endpoint, i have to enable regional VNET integration for my Web App as i read in MS Docs.
So at the moment i have two subnets in Central US and one of the subnets i have to dedicate for creating VNET integration for my Web Apps. The other subnet will be hosting my SQL Private Endpoint.
I have already enabled Global VNET peering between Primary Central US and the Secondary VNET in East US 2.
So i would like to know whether during a disaster and after a failover happens for my SQL from Primary Central US to secondary East US 2, will my Web Apps automatically connect to the SQL FO group read/write listener after i enable private link for my Azure SQL.
I don't understand what it means by this below as per the link :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/private-web-app/private-web-app

Global peering
Any service in any Azure region that can connect through the Virtual Network can reach the database's private endpoint, for example through Virtual Network peering in hub-and-spoke topologies. However, for App Service regional VNet Integration, the peered Virtual Networks must be located in the same Azure region.

As per the line "However, for App Service regional VNet Integration, the peered Virtual Networks must be located in the same Azure region.", my peered virtual network is from Central US to East US 2 which is like Global Peering.
So how this statement applies to in my case.

Looking forward to some pointers

Comment: Does KarthikBhyresh-MT's answer useful to you ? If yes, I will give him 100 reputation bounty.

Comment: That statement is describing a scenario when the DBs have failed over to secondary region while Web App remains active on primary region - it isn't supported. You have not made it clear but for the DR to really work you must have the App Service also created in secondary region. During the DR secondary region would be used for both App Service and SQL, and in this case the private endpoint would continue to work.

Comment: amit_g I have tested failing over the SQL from Primary to Secondary Private Endpoint. My web apps were still connecting to the Secondary Instance being in the primary region. Why you say it isn't supported? This is the case of a partial failover where you fail over just one service and keep the other service in the primary. You can have partial failover or a complete failover. Both are mentioned in the article https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/example-scenario/sql-failover/app-service-private-sql-multi-region